# is IPSEC Authentication between local domain hosts a part of normal behaviour in a Windows network?

Tags: authentication, ipsec

I am seeing lot of IPSEC Authentication messages in eventlogs of Windows domain hosts.  I was wondering if this -  setting up IPSEC connections between domain workstations is a part of normal Windows behaviour?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the versions of Windows and the basic AD configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: probably normal.

Windows server 2008 can use IPSec (if configured) for [domain and server isolation](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/windows_os_security/Deploying-IPsec-Server-Domain-Isolation-Windows-Server-2008-Group-Policy-Part1.html).

It depends on the configurations and the Group Policies involved. Aside from this answer, you'll need to head over to a Windows admin forum or [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the IPSEC protocol is simply said an security protocol over the controller towards the workstations, its part of the regular traffic, so nothing to be worried about